# UIActivityController + UIDocumentInteraction

Tags: ios, uiactivity

I create a UIActivictyController in my app, but i want to give the option to open in dropbox, pages and other programs installed.

I know that UIDocumentInteractionController give this options, but how can i give this options in UIActivityController?

Answer (score 0):

[REActivityViewController](https://github.com/romaonthego/REActivityViewController) is probably what you are looking for. It also allows color icon images as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Using UIDocumentInteractionController, ios gives you an interface similar to UIActivityController, but also with Open In apps option enabled according to the file extension.